# What is a good Fax Server to use?

Tags: .net, windows, fax

Any recommendation of a Fax server to use in Windows? Looking for good API support for incoming faxes. (Lots of them are good for outgoing). I want to route incoming faxes to email programmatically after the server gets the fax and set Whitelist of phone numbers to filter spam - all in code.

Comment: We went with VentaFax. Runs as service, good logging, callerid works. About $100. While there is no API, it has enough routing features to support White list, black list, and emailing the fax out. (enough for us).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend looking at Biscom. They have both fax server and fax hosting solutions. They have been in business for 23 years and are a very stable company.  http://biscom.com/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

The two best solutions I have found are [hylafax.org](http://www.hylafax.org/) and jConnect. The advantages of hylafax are its 100% free and open source. Since you are posting here its highly likely that you are have the technical chops to get this going and if you do you will be well rewarded. [Haylafax](http://www.hylafax.org/) is full featured and can do all the sending and receiving you want for free. On the not so free side [jConnect](https://www.j2.com/) is free if you use a local number they only charge for toll free. Both are great solutions but I would try [Halafax](http://www.hylafax.org/) first.

Hope that helps! Let me know what you think of Hylafax.

*edit* Didn't see your above comment, Hylafax has no windows support, sorry :( But they have pre compiled bins for these...

Debian Ubuntu Fedora Mandrake Red Hat CentOS Solaris SUSE FreeBSD OpenBSD NetBSD

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the FAXCOM [windows fax server](http://www.biscom.com/products_solutions/faxcom_server.htm) :)

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend checking out [link text](http://www.freeswitch.org/) as an option.  It will run on windows or linux, written in C and it's VERY efficient/fast.  If you will be doing a lot of faxing and don't mind taking a little time to setup the system, this is the way to go.

This is a free solution, you would only need to pay for VoIP service from a carrier to run. There are thousands of these companies to choose from and rates are very cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used MyFax.com, they're a hosted service. They send you faxes as email attachments - very convenient if you already have the code that handles incoming mail.

Comment: Thanks. Service usually charge about 10 cents a page. We intend to get 5K pages per month so the fees get a little high. Would like one I can install in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

PamFax provides a fax service that can be used with a API from various programming languages (e.g. PHP, Python, Ruby). http://www.pamfax.biz/en/developers/introduction/ has all the details. Disclaimer: I work for PamConsult, the company behind PamFax.

Comment: Be careful about your promotion. You state your affiliation, which is good. But if all (or at least a significant amount) of your answers relate to PamFax, you might end up in a bit of trouble. Try to participate more generally throughout SO.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out [eFax Corporate](http://enterprise.efax.com) if you need a custom hosted business fax solution and fax API. They have a developer kit, custom admin portal and are secure.  They could be what you're looking for.